# Powershell where-object return code

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling, exit-code

I'm returning to powershell from bash after a long time, and I've found the where object behavior to be quite confusing.

Why does the following snippet return success? Nothing is found! Why does this not return failure like a grep would?

```
C:> Get-Process | ?{$_.name -like "laksdjfajsdfkjasdkf"}
C:> echo $?
True
```

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3359

Comment: PowerShell cmdlets do **not** have return codes as native executables have. It can not return failure without `ErrorRecord`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# Run the command and, in addition to outputting to the console,
# collect the results in variable $result, via common parameter -OutVariable / -ov 
# If you do NOT need to output to the console, simply use:
#     $result = Get-Process | ...
Get-Process | ? { $_.name -like "laksdjfajsdfkjasdkf" } -ov result

# Test if the result is empty (using implicit Boolean conversion)
if (-not $result) { Write-Warning "Nothing matched." }
```

---

**PowerShell's automatic (Boolean) `$?` variable in PowerShell is *not* the (abstract) equivalent of exit codes in traditional shells**, as PetSerAl points out.

**`$?` just tells you whether the last statement *succeeded*** and the **rules surrounding it are complicated**, as [the GitHub discussion that Owain Esau links to](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3359) shows.
***Succeeded* means that no *errors* occurred, and a filtering operation not returning anything *is* success by that definition.**
In short: **`$?` is of limited usefulness in PowerShell.**

However, the **exit code of the most recently executed *external* program is reflected in automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`**, so had you actually invoked `grep`, its exit code would be reflected there.
(And while `$?` is set *immediately after* execution of an external program to reflect `$True` if the exit code was `0` and `$False` otherwise, `$?` may already reflect something *else* by the time the statement finishes, depending on the specifics of the statement, such as enclosing the call in `(...)`)

In the case at hand **you're looking to determine whether the filtering operation** performed by the call to the `Where-Object` cmdlet (invoked via its built-in alias `?`) **returned any matches**, but **in PowerShell that status is *not* reflected anywhere separately**.
Therefore, you **must examine the *output itself*** to determine whether anything matched, as shown in the snippet at the top.

There are no *errors* in this scenario, but for the sake of completeness: 
**PowerShell's *error handling*** is sophisticated, but complex, and again unlike that of traditional shells; you can find an [overview here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).